# Transitioning to an abstract class

Tags: java, drawing, 2d, abstract

I am desperately trying to implement some things which I don't think I fully understand. I am attempting to set it up so the commented out actions can be taken (I will need to change syntax but I want to make sure I am on the right track first).

Am I going about this the right way? Where will my drawing actions go if not in the draw method? I get lots of errors when I move it there. Thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    abstract class graphic {
        public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        private int[] location = new int[] {screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2}; 
    }

    public class gladiator extends graphic {
        void draw() {
        //g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        //g2d.fillArc(location[0], location[1], 100, 100, 45, 90);
        //g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        //g2d.fillArc((location[0]+50-10),(location[1]+50-10), 20, 20, 0, 360);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //              setLocation((location[0]+1),location[1]);
                repaint();
                System.out.println("repainting");
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y){
        //this.location[0] = x;
        //this.location[1] = y;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        jf.add(new Test());

        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

My original code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    private int[] location = new int[2]; 

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillArc(location[0], location[1], 100, 100, 45, 90);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillArc((location[0]+50-10),(location[1]+50-10), 20, 20, 0, 360);

        new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setLocation((location[0]+50),50);
                repaint();
                System.out.println("repainting");
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y){
        this.location[0] = x;
        this.location[1] = y;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,500));
        jf.setLocation(100,100);
        jf.add(new Test());

        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit: Should have included this bit, first commenter was right.

The error is cannot find symbol, referring to g2d or g, whichever. I take it to mean that drawing can only happen inside of paint components and that I will have to find a way to include all the instructions for drawing there. I want to make sure I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong, though as this is my first brush with both abstract classes and 2d drawing in java. Also, I know the location[0] etc will not work as is. Lets ignore that.

The bottom code is what I am trying to accomplish (at least at first), but I am trying to use something similar to the top code to create multiple instances of it which can operate independently.

Comment: What currently breaks if you uncomment the code? (Include the errors.) Your question amounts to "does this code look ok" which is more easily answered by a compiler than any of us. :)

Comment: The error is cannot find symbol, referring to g2d or g, whichever. I took it to mean that drawing could only happen inside of paint components and that I would have to find a way to include all the instructions for drawing there. I wanted to make sure I wasn't just doing something fundamentally wrong, though as this is my first brush with both abstract classes and 2d drawing in java.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It shows a shape which I couln't identify moving offscreen in a southeasterly direction. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @Arend Which code did you run? The bottom code is what I am trying to accomplish (at least at first), but I am trying to use something similar to the top code to create multiple instances of it which can operate independently.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I misunderstood what the second piece of code was for (which was the one I ran) - I thought it was in response to @Don's comment. Looking at the first piece of code, I am puzzled by what it is you are trying to do. At the very least the `draw` method should get the `Graphics2D` object it is trying to draw on as a parameter, and `location` should not be declared as `private` in `graphics`. That will get rid of the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the timer out of paintcomponent.
2. You have declared an abstract class that has a draw method that needs a `Graphics2D` object to be able to draw, it has no access to it. It also makes little sense to declare a class just to hold two values (screensize and location) if that class also does stuff like drawing.
3. To fix the issues with 2, you can either let your `gladiator` extend `JComponent`, override its `paintcomponent` and place your `draw()` code in there and add gladiator to the panel as a component.
4. You can alternatively do active rendering, which means that you get the `Graphic2D` object of your canvas (the panel in this case) and take control of the rendering yourself instead of relying on swing.

Since you are working with swing I will give you a working example of what you probably intend to do. If you have more specific questions please do leave a comment.

```
public class Test extends JPanel {


public static abstract class graphic extends JComponent {

    public Dimension dim = new Dimension(500, 500);
    private int[] loc = new int[] { 250, 250 };

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }


    public int[] getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public Dimension getDim() {
        return dim;
    }

}

public static class gladiator extends graphic {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillArc(getLoc()[0], getLoc()[1], 100, 100, 45, 90);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillArc((getLoc()[0] + 50 - 10), (getLoc()[1] + 50 - 10), 20,
                20, 0, 360);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Test canvas = new Test();
    gladiator gladiator = new gladiator();

    canvas.add(gladiator);
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

This renders

[image]